# About iterator of containers

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdvector, dereference

I do not know, why does it output `1024`?

```
vector<int> default_container = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,78,8,1024 };
cout << *default_container.end() << endl; // 0
default_container.pop_back();

for (auto it : default_container) 
{
    cout << it << ",";
}
cout << endl;

cout << *default_container.end() << endl;   // 1024 why？why？why？why？
cout << *--default_container.end() << endl; // 8
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your program has **[Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**!

You are de-referencing the end iterator, at the lines

```
cout << *default_container.end() << endl;
...
cout << *default_container.end() << endl;
```

which gives you undefined behavior.  Form *cppreference.com* the [`std::vector::end, std::vector::cend`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end)

[image]

> Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the vector.
> **This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.**

Means, anything can be happened; therefore you shouldn't be relaying on its result and should not be doing it!

---

That being said, it looks like that you want to access the last element in the vector. If that the case, **for a non-empty vector**  you have multiple other (safe) choices:

1. Using [`std::vector::back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back)

   ```
   // prints first 8 from last; due to "default_container.pop_back()"  
   std::cout << default_container.back();
   ```
2. Using [`std::prev`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev)

   ```
   #include <iterator>

   // prints first 8 from last; due to "default_container.pop_back()"  
   std::cout << *std::prev(default_container.end());
   ```
3. Using reverse iterator [`std::rbegin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin)

   ```
   // prints first 8 from last; due to "default_container.pop_back()"  
   std::cout << *std::rbegin(default_container);
   ```

---

As a side note, see: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @littleZ Then have a nice start with world of behaviors ;)

Comment: You might want to mention that your approaches all assume a non-empty vector, and have undefined behaviour for an empty container.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the pointing out. I had only focused on OP's case, which is non-empty. Might be helpful for future readers!

Comment: In `*std::prev(default_container.end());` I think the `std::` is only optional due to ADL. Same with `std::rbegin`.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 But nothing (begin explicit) wrong with it too.

Comment: @JeJo Why does forward_list not support back in c++? I'm confused.

Comment: @Const yeah, definitely. I suppose it is ultimately a matter of opinion in the end, I was just mentioning the option of removing it.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer says it all.
In other words you're not supposed to use end() for anything else then comparing an iterator to.
Eg.

```
for (auto it = container.begin(); it < container.end(); ++it)
```

Also note that your line for (auto it : default_container)
isn't creating an iterator but literally an int.

```
// foreach value in container
for(int value : default_container) 
{
  cout << value;
}
```

note that if you're not planning to change the values you're iterating over you can use this :

```
for(const auto value : default_container) {}
```

or if your containter contains objects (instance of classes)

```
for(const auto& object : container) {}
```